# The community user going crazy, bug, human error or attack?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, usuario-community

I encountered the [Community ♦](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) edited [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1631/1067):

from this:
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/1631/1

to this:
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/1631/2

Is this a bug? Someone playing with the system? an attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community ♦ owned edit suggestions are those made by anonymous users. What happened here is that some users [accepted this suggested edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/616) although they should have rejected it. So, there is nothing hacked nor it's a bug, just a "human error".

Comment: Thanks @Joul. IMHO, Sergio and Laura want a short email inviting them to really read what they are approving. It is supposed the revision of newbies edits is to help the quality of the site, but also to prevent vandalism, and they both in this case shows that they're just blindingly approving anything. why? are they just looking for badges?. I really don't get it!

Comment: @jachguate Well, this is why also we can rollback edits. About your last question, they are implementing a method to audit users so they can check if they are reviewing correctly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing By now I think it only works in SO and not all review queues, but they plan to expand it to other SE sites.